# Move cells in same workbook with loop

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have the following problem:
an excel sheet with an unknown amount of rows, and in each row an unknown amount of products with the amount of products sold.
For example: 1 Coke 2 Fanta,...
Where for example 1 is situated in A1, Coke in B1, 2 in C1,...

Now I would like to get all amounts in Column A and all products in Column B, but each amount has to stay linked to its product!

Since I dont know how many rows there are per day, this should be a loop until there is no more data in "Axx"

Is there somebody who could help me out? thanks!

Comment: Post the code you have tried before, SO isn't meant to just give you the code. Attempt the problem and we'll help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I do agree with Alex D, you gotta give us something to work with! but I also know the anger macros can give, so heres a code all youve got to do is write the list of products in column C. This will allow for a varying amount

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ProductLastRow As Long
    ProductLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'will find last row
    Set myrng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & LastRow) 'Will find the product name
    Set myrng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'Will find product amount
    Range("D1:D" & ProductLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(" & myrng1.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC[-1]," & myrng2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"

End Sub
```

Chin Up!